# Plotting a regression with two variables

Tags: r, plot, graph, regression

I'm trying to plot a regression that looks something like this:

```
limod <- lm(y~(x1+x2)*Group, data=file1 )
```

How can I plot x1 against y given the covariate effect of x2 in the linear model?
I tried to use termplot but that seems to give me a plot of partial residuals versus the original variable. This is hard to interpret.  I want the outcome variable plotted against x1 but with the effect of x2. I also tried plot(limod) but its not what I'm looking for.
File1:

```
Group | x1    |  x2   | y
______|_______|_______|_________________
CON   | 0.5   | 1     | 0.23
MED   | -.1   | 0.13  | 0.44
MED   | 0.01  | 0.41  | 0.99
MED   | 0.12  | -0.3  | 0.81
CON   | 0.88  | 0.2   | 0.75
MED   | 0.54  | 0.56  | 0.41
CON   | 0.22  | 0.66  | 0.14
CON   | 0.94  | 0.93  | 0.51
```

Plotting the y~ x1 is very different than plotting the y~x1+x2
I'm interested in x1 against y but with x2 effect
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should explain what is meant by a plot of a linear regression outcome against one variable but excluding the other.

Comment: It would help to see some/all of the data from `file1` in a plain text format. It sounds like [sjPlot](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/) could be useful here, in particular [plot_model() with type = "int"](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_interactions.html).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_regline_equation.html?

Comment: I updated my question